# SQLite limiting and ordering to page on iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have an iPhone app, built in Xamarin, that stores objects to a local SQLite database. As it takes a long time to load all of the data, I am loading it 20 records at a time, and loading more as the user scrolls.

I am paging by CreatedDate, and this is stored as an Integer field by its DateTime.Ticks property (the number of 100 nanoseconds since DateTime.MinValue). I always pass the oldest loaded CreatedDate to the read function.

- Integer column: 8 bytes signed
- DateTime.Ticks: 8 bytes signed

The code to write the CreatedDate is as follows:

```
var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@date";
param.Value = myObject.DateCreated.Value.Ticks;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

And the code to read the next page is as follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedDate < " +
                  (offset.HasValue ? offset.Value.Ticks : DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks) + 
                  " ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT " + pageSize;
```

I can tell that the dates are correct, because my sections in my UITableView are based on their CreatedDates.

**So here's all the weird behavior (i.e. my question).**

**I started off in the simulator.** At first, I was using DESC and it was returning the oldest objects. Then I switched it to ASC and it was returning the newest objects. This seems backwards. Then, it magically started working correctly with DESC. Paging began working in the simulator, and still works.

**Then I switched to a real iPhone.** The DESC and ASC issue showed up again, but this time has not fixed itself (ASC returns the most recent objects). Either way, when I scroll to the bottom of the UITableView, the load gets called again with the correct offset, but it gets no data back (and therefore all paging stops).

**Things I know.**

- All of the data is in the table, because if I `SELECT *` I get everything with the correct dates back. I have also written all of the dates to the console to be sure.
- My newest date is 635194634041230000
- My oldest date is 635166796800000000
- The offset date that returns no rows is 635193909600000000

**Note. I'm OK with constructive criticism on how I'm doing this. I'll upvote if I like it enough. But if you post an answer with that information in it, please also try to address the current issue I'm having.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I did not post the relevant code. If the record didn't exist yet, I was writing DateTime.Now to the column. So depending on what order the WCF service returned the results (descending or ascending by date), my ordering could be backwards. I'm not quite sure why it was refusing to page, but I'm guessing it had something to do with precision or whether the database was persisting on the device. Both problems are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in front of a computer, so I can't really debug your code atm, however, I thought I'd link to some generic code I wrote for MonoTouch to dynamically page data from SQLite:

https://github.com/jstedfast/MonoTouch.SQLite/blob/master/MonoTouch.SQLite/SQLiteTableModel.cs

This code uses SQLite-net and not System.Data, but it may still help.

The core logic for paging in and out is in GetItem().

Comment: Well I found out that the bug was on my end and I did not post the important code. I think I'll leave this question up though so that this answer sticks around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your Database, what datatype did you set for the CreateData column?  If you used Integer then Ticks should be ok.

> 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did use integers. There is obviously an error since I posted the question, but this doesn't really give me an answer. I may be deleting this question soon. I think it was a stupid bug on my end (writing the wrong createddate). I just can't test on the device until late tonight to make sure I'm right.